# RuntimeException caused by SQLiteException, syntax error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select

I'm new to the Android development and SQLite databases, so please bear with me on that one (also, my first question on this site, hope it's OK).

So, my database consists of three tables:

1. Table `records`
2. Table `locations`
3. Table `tags`

This is how I've created tables:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "recordsDatabase";

//Common columns
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";

//Tables
public static final String TABLE_RECORDS = "records";
public static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";
public static final String TABLE_TAGS = "tags";

//Records table
public static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "date";
public static final String STARTINGHOUR = "startingHour";
public static final String FINISHINGHOUR = "finishingHour";
public static final String COMMENTS = "comments";
public static final String LOCATIONS_ID = "locationsID";
public static final String TAGS_ID = "tagsID";

//Create table statements
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_RECORDS = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_RECORDS + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    + NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME,"
    + STARTINGHOUR + " TEXT,"
    + FINISHINGHOUR + " TEXT,"
    + COMMENTS + " TEXT,"
    + LOCATIONS_ID + " INTEGER, "
    + TAGS_ID + " INTEGER, "
    + "FOREIGN KEY(" + LOCATIONS_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(id),"
    + "FOREIGN KEY(" + TAGS_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_TAGS + "(id))";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
    + NAME_COLUMN + ")";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_TAGS = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_TAGS + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
    + NAME_COLUMN + ")";
```

A bit later on, in the `onOpen` method, I've created the following PRAGMA statement:

```
if(!db.isReadOnly()) db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
```

As you can see, I'm using foreign keys to establish a relationship between those tables. As I've mentioned, I'm completely new to the SQLite databases, so there might be a problem here as well, but I'm not receiving any failures on that part.

However, I was being informed about the following error:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 ... java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
...
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT records.id, records.name ,date, startingHour, finishingHour, comments, locationsID, tagsID locations.name, tags.name FROM records records, locations locations, tags tags WHERE records.locationsID = locations.id AND tagsID = tags.id
```

which points to the following lines of code:

```
public static final String RECORDS_ID_WITH_PREFIX = "rec.id";
public static final String RECORDS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX = "rec.name";
public static final String LOCATIONS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX = "loc.name";
public static final String TAGS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX = "tg.name";
private static final String WHERE_ID_EQUALS = DatabaseHelper.ID + " =?";

//...some blocks of code in between...\\

String query = "SELECT " + RECORDS_ID_WITH_PREFIX + ", "       
    + RECORDS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + " ,"
    + DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT + ", "
    + DatabaseHelper.STARTINGHOUR + ", "
    + DatabaseHelper.FINISHINGHOUR + ", "
    + DatabaseHelper.COMMENTS + ", "
    + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONS_ID + ", "
    + DatabaseHelper.TAGS_ID + " "+ LOCATIONS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + ", " + TAGS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + " FROM "
    + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORDS + " rec, " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOCATIONS + " loc, " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAGS + " tg "
    + " WHERE rec." + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONS_ID + " = loc." + DatabaseHelper.ID + " AND "
    + DatabaseHelper.TAGS_ID + " = tg." + DatabaseHelper.ID;
```

The reason why I'm asking this question is that the `SELECT` query should follow this syntax:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table name] WHERE [conditions];
```

but if I look at my syntax, I see nothing wrong. Now the reason why I'm using the `RECORDS_ID_WITH_PREFIX`, `RECORDS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX`, `LOCATIONS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX` and `LOCATIONS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX` is to avoid confusion because `id` and `name` columns are common in all tables. Is someone willing to take a look and help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Also, if you think there's something wrong with my question, please let me know so that in future same mistakes are not repeated.

Comment: you need to post your crash stacktrace. and better, read it first carefuly

Comment: What a kind of HORRIBLE QUERIES! Why can't you use standard JOINs?

Comment: I do apologize if my queries bring discomfort, this application is for a school project and there are guidelines we have to follow. In some other instance, I actually am using `JOIN` statements! And I do agree that `JOIN` statements are much more legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+ DatabaseHelper.TAGS_ID + " "+ LOCATIONS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + ", " +
                           ^^^
```

missing comma

Comment: Wow, that actually solved my problem... I mean, I'm facing new ones already but at least that one is solved. Thank you so much!